# Xcode 4.2 Beta and iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-4.2, ios5

I am having a problem with developing a new project using Xcode 4.2 (the beta) and deploying this onto an iPod touch running iOS 4.2.1. I told xcode that the built target was iOS 4.2, but it does not seem to want to run on it at all. The project builds successfully, but then never actually runs on the iPod.

However, it does work fine if I am using an iPod touch that has iOS 4.3 on it. Does anyone know how I could fix this or what the problem may be. I was wondering if there was an easy way that did not involve me pretty much redoing everything in an older version of xcode with the older SDK's installed.

Comment: Questions regarding this type of Beta are under NDA and should be asked in the [Apple Developer Forums](http://devforums.apple.com/).

Comment: a)Devforums is a better place for this. b)Read the release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been getting this kind of problems too! so I just decide having 2 xcode! I still have xcode4 for main development, but also have installed the beta version, in a different directory, so a I have

> /Developer

For xcode 4, and

> /Developer/beta

for xcode beta version!

Answer (score 0):

I will not point to specific things because of the nda, but from previous experience this could be due to innovations in the next version, look carefully at the options for creating the project with all the checkmarks
, using classes and read that added a new